# OpenGL: mipmap generation for bitmap font makes it darker when scaled down

Tags: opengl, fonts, rendering, mipmaps

I'm loading a font from a TGA texture. I generate the mipmap using the `gluBuild2DMipmaps()` function.

When the font has a certain size, it looks very good. But when it gets smaller, it gets darker and darker whenever it reaches a new mipmap level.

This is how I create the texture:

```
void TgaLoader::bindTexture(unsigned int* texture)
{
    tImageTGA *pBitMap = m_tgaImage;

    if(pBitMap == 0)
    {
        return;
    }

    glGenTextures(1, texture);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, *texture);

    gluBuild2DMipmaps(GL_TEXTURE_2D,
                        pBitMap->channels,
                        pBitMap->size_x,
                        pBitMap->size_y,
                        textureType,
                        GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE,
                        pBitMap->data);


    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D,GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER,GL_LINEAR_MIPMAP_NEAREST);
    glTexParameterf( GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);
}
```

This makes the text look like this (it should be white):

[image]

Barely visible.

If I change the `GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER` to basically ignore mipmaps (using `GL_LINEAR` for example), it looks like this:

[image]

I've tried different filter options and also tried using `glGenerateMipmap()` instead of `gluBuild2DMipmaps()`, but I always end up with the same result.

What's wrong with the code?

Comment: In simple words, at automatic mipmap generation 4 texels (in a quad) are interpolated and stored to the next mipmap level with half resolution. This causes that the text gets darker and darker by each level. If you want to improve the result then you have to use textures with different size and text rendered in different sizes and you have to load this textures to the different mipmap levels. Or you use a technique like [Distance Fields](https://blog.mapbox.com/drawing-text-with-signed-distance-fields-in-mapbox-gl-b0933af6f817)

Comment: Would it be enough to make as many textures as needed dividing the font texture by 2 with a random image editor?

So for example, if I start with a 512x512, scale down to 256x256 to make mipmap level 1, then 128x128 for level 2, and so on.

Comment: [Generate your own miplevels using gamma-correct scaling](https://stackoverflow.com/a/832314/44729). Or use a [sRGB texture and `glGenerateMipmap()` will do it for you](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22352552/44729).